# Null pointer exception with TextView on android with no apparent reason

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

i have a very annoying bug that i couldn't figure out what causes it.  it seens that i am getting a null pointer exception when trying to start an activity from another activity with an Intent.     i tried all possible solutions i could think of,checked the syntax houndreds of times, tried to setContentView with main layout before the new layout..nothing!
 I need some urgent help here.  I have everything declared in the manifest,and the layout xml files.  the problem relies in the ShowNoteActivity,called by the main activity (from onItemClick() method) :       I get nullpointerexception from the logcat and bunch of other errors i don't know what they are.

anyway,this is the relevant code,tell me if you need more.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener ,OnItemClickListener{

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "assaf.notepad.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
        String[]notes = db.listNotes();
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notes);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        ImageButton addNoteBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_note);
        addNoteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNoteActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
        String[]notesContent = db.getNoteContent();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowNoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, notesContent[position]);
        startActivity(intent);



    }



}
```

and this is the problematic activity!!

```
public class ShowNoteActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_note);
        textView.setText(text);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_note);
    }

}
```

this is the logcat

```
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{assaf.notepad/assaf.notepad.ShowNoteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at assaf.notepad.ShowNoteActivity.onCreate(ShowNoteActivity.java:19)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-19 03:18:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  ... 11 more
```

the relevant xml ,the "ShowNoteActivity"  xml ,with the problematic textView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/board"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/delete_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/paper"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>




</RelativeLayou
```

t>

this is not a database problem or something like that, the problem still exists even if i try to pass a "hello world"  string to the new activity.  the program always crashes when invoking the new activity.

this is the xml manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="assaf.notepad"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="assaf.notepad.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="assaf.notepad.AddNoteActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="assaf.notepad.ShowNoteActivity">

        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `"for no apparent reason..."` -- there's a reason for it, believe me. Keep looking at the null variables to see where you *think* you've created them.

Comment: Which line is ShowNoteActivity line 19?

Comment: You should call `findViewById(R.id.show_note)` after you have called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_note)`

Comment: didn't help!  tried it right now and still crashing

Comment: clean your project and run it again

Comment: did that..didn't help unfortunately.  i don't know what to do..tried everything i could think of and all the suggestion i found from others and nothing solved it

Comment: did u print that value, that u put in bundle to start `ShowNoteActivity`. were u getting the value null or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to access a TextView before you call `setContentView` in your ShowNoteActivity. Your code should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_note);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_note);
textView.setText(text);
```

Comment: I will try that,although i think that i tried it before with no sucess.  but i will try again just to make sure

Answer (score 0):

try

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_note);    
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_note);
if(textView!=null && text!=null)
{
    Log.d("Mytag","Everything is right");
    textView.setText(text);
}
else
{
if(textView==null)
    Log.d("Mytag","Textview is null");
else
    Log.d("Mytag","Text is null");
}
```

Comment: did the application crash? Add a log to the first if condition.

Comment: yes the application crashes on me all this time.  it starts fine,but only when i press a certain button (that trigers the problematic activity)  the program crashes

Comment: now i am getting this error 
02-19 04:14:44.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{assaf.notepad/assaf.notepad.ShowNoteActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: @user2030118 You're now getting another problem. As I keep saying, ***Update*** your question with the new codes and LogCat so that *if* this issue gets resolved, future readers don't have to search to figure out all the problem deails. Not to mention, you're also leaving the answerers in the dark.

Comment: how about you comment everything except the setContentView line in your ShowNoteActivity class. If it is still crashing then you have a problem in your xml because the above error states that too.

Comment: Is your xml file name same as entered in class file ?

Comment: The content view is fine..look at the code.  I tried everything

Comment: Your problem is definitely in xml, Maybe the drawables or colors you have used are not correct. remove them and try again.

Comment: but i can see the xml file output in the graphical editor just fine. and i don't get any errors from eclipse about any typing mistakes

Comment: post your project to github or someplace else because it is getting difficult to find the problem now. Also update your question with the latest information.